# Deploy Tableau Three-node configuration on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, tableau-api, high-availability

For deploy tableau server, can i deploy tableau server HA in three-node configuration on Azure Virtual Machine like this link : [High Availability Installations (HA) Three-node configuration](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/server_baseline_config.htm#two-node-installation--specialized-for-extract-heavy-environments)[image]

How i do? who have experience about deploy tableau environment on Azure, please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running Tableau Server on a Microsoft Azure VM is an excellent choice if you want the flexibility of scaling up and scaling out without having to purchase and maintain an expensive fleet of servers.

For instance, you can configure Tableau Server as three-node to be highly available, and integrate with all of the common enterprise applications (for example, Active Directory) that many organizations rely on.

For more details, you could refer to:

- [Install Tableau Server on Microsoft Azure](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ts_azure_welcome.htm)
- [Example: Install and Configure a Three-Node HA Cluster](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/distrib_ha_install_3node.htm#a-threenode-system)